# Can I randomly select 100 records from the output with DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

I’d like to obtain a random 100 records from a query (if there are more than 100) in DolphinDB but have no idea what function to use.
Here is the query statement.

```
result = select * from loadTable('dfs://TSDB', 'data') where time between 2021.01.01T00:00:00.000 : 2022.01.01T00:10:00.000, id in ids
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the script in the example:

```
ids = ["024bafec-0adc-4e51-bffe-793085c0559e", "018b8110-ca1b-4f1e-97b2-0363c8ed49ae", "0164480b-11a8-4312-91e0-c96f9faac95c"]
result = select * from loadTable('dfs://GZB_TSDB', 'data') where time between 2021.01.01T00:00:00.000 : 2021.01.01T00:10:00.000, id in ids
iif(result.size() <= 100, result, result[sort rand(0..(result.size()-1),100)]) // The result may contain duplicate values.
iif(result.size() <= 100, result, result[sort(take(shuffle(0..(result.size()-1)),100), false)])
```